# Recommendations about procedures and policies for an application security strategy?

Tags: web-application, appsec, hardening

I need to develop an application security strategy for a web application product. Do you have any recommendations as far as procedures and policies are concerned?

Any inputs / guidelines or relevant URLs will much be appreciated.

Comment: What have you found so far? Please show us that you have done some preparatory work.

Comment: We are not here to do your job for you, if you are going to post a question at least show that you made some effort by sharing documentation and references you already found.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://owasp.org/

Comment: This has *got* to be a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

You should follow web security standards outlined by [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

> The Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) is a 501(c)(3)
>   worldwide not-for-profit charitable organization focused on improving
>   the security of software. Our mission is to make software security
>   visible, so that individuals and organizations worldwide can make
>   informed decisions about true software security risks.